# Graphql subscriptions - Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined when using withFilter

Tags: javascript, websocket, graphql

I have an app that uses graphql subscriptions for chat functionality. I have managed to successfully get the subscription working however after introducing the `withFilter` function in order to filter which clients the messages get sent to I am getting the following error on the frontend:

> Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined

Here is my subscription resolver:

```
const { PubSub, withFilter } = require('graphql-yoga');

const pubsub = new PubSub();
pubsub.ee.setMaxListeners(30);

const Subscription = {
  detailedConversation: withFilter(
    () => pubsub.asyncIterator('detailedConversation'),
    (payload, args) => {
      return true;
    }
  )
};

module.exports = {
  Subscription,
  pubsub
};
```

As the second parameter of withFilter has to be a function that returns a boolean, I have just set this to return true for the time being.

Graphql-yoga uses graphql-subscriptions under the hood and after reading the documentation on implementation [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#filters) I can't see what i'm doing wrong?

FYI the error occurs when attempting to subscribe for the first time to a conversation, not whilst sending a message or anything

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but gonna give my solution, to others that might come looking for exactly the same solution...

First thing to note is that I'm using the [graphql-redis-subscriptions](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions) implementation instead of the default implementation.

```js
   userUpdated: {
        subscribe: withFilter((_, args, { pubsub }) => pubsub.asyncIterator('userUpdated'), (payload, vars) => vars.usersId.includes(payload.userUpdated.id))
    }
```

[documentation link](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions#using-both-arguments-and-payload-to-filter-events)

Answer (score 0):

you just check the two arguments are the same then return your actions.

```
UserUpdated:{
    withFilter(
        () => pubsub.asyncIterator('UserUpdated'),
        (payload, variables) => {            
            return (payload.UserUpdated.id === variables.channelid);
        },
    ),
}
```